# Firebase rules display only vip members

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to display data only for vip users. I use the code below, but every user can saw the data anyway.

I want to hide actors data from normal users and display for vip users.

```
"tvshow1": {
          ".indexOn": ["actors"],
            ".read": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('VIP').val() == 'Yes'",
            ".write": "data.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('VIP').val() == 'Yes'"
        },
```

Database structure:

```
tvshow1

| title:

| date:

| actors:
```

Members

```
|id:

   |VIP:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "root"

```
 ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('VIP').val() == 'Yes'"
```

same goes for write